# What version of Kohana am I using?

Tags: version, kohana

Where in the Kohana framework can I find out the version information?

Everything I look at in the tutorials opposes to what I view in my application. I believe this to be a version issue as the methods and calls are slightly different between the documentation and my install.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At least for versions >= 3.0, the version number for Kohana is located in `system/classes/kohana/core.php`.

It will be in this form:

```
// Release version and codename
const VERSION  = '3.2.0';
```

Since [that](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Kohana#constant:VERSION)'s just a constant, you can access it through php with `Kohana::VERSION`.

Comment: I don't know what Kohana version you're referring to (maybe v2.X), but this is not correct for v3.X, the current stable branch.

Answer (score 5):

Check out these constants in the Kohana class:

```
// Release version and codename
const VERSION  = '3.0.8';
const CODENAME = 'großen jäger';
```

So Kohana::VERSION and Kohana::CODENAME.

Answer (score 3):

The file you are looking for is `system/classes/kohana/core.php`.

Answer (score 1):

For Kohana 2.x look for KOHANA_VERSION in system/core/Bootstrap.php