# Finding version of kohana used in project

Tags: php, kohana

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is Kohana Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058949/where-is-kohana-version)

I'm new to both PHP and kohana.  I need to figure out what version of kohana is in use with a particular project.  Looking though the .php files, there aren't headers with the version. I see a lot of documentation in markdown format, but have yet to find one that spells out the version.

The version of kohana I know is 3.0.0 or greater.

Comment: It is a duplicate, I'm sorry. I'll flag for merging with the above.

Comment: The accepted answer on the duplicate is actually community wiki, so you guys can feel free to edit it to improve it. Merging these would just create a chain of (nearly) duplicate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `system/classes/kohana/core.php`. There will be something in this form:

```
// Release version and codename
const VERSION  = '3.2.0';
```

Comment: I marked this as solved because I like being able to dig it out of the source (at the moment it was more convenient), but I'll try the Luwe's answer for other products... sounds more general.

Comment: They are different ways of getting at the same variable, so you're good either way. It's nice to be able to access it programatically as Luwe suggests, though!

Answer (score 4):

Try `echo Kohana::VERSION` it will show you the version number.

It can be found here in the documentation: 
http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Kohana#constant:VERSION